# Using BeautifulSoup to pick up texts separated by ":"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Webpage source code contains segments like below:

```
<TR>
<TD width="40%">Company No. <I>(CO.)</I> : <B>056</B></TD>
<TD width="40%">Country Code. <I>(CC.)</I> : <B>3532 </B></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Register <I>(Reg.)</I> : <B>FD522</B></TD>
<TD>Credit<I>(CD.) </I>: <B>YES</B></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Type <I>(TP.)</I> : <B>PRIVATE</B></TD></TR>
```

Short form of the titles like CO., CC. Reg. CD. and TP. are of italic fonts. Contents like 056, 3532, FD522 etc are of bold fonts. They are separated by “:”.

I want to extract their titles and contents separately by BeautifulSoup however not successful.

I am using:

```
soup.find_all("td")
```

but it doesn’t produce well.  it returns like "Company No. *(CO.)* : **056**" in one line but i want to have them separately, like "Company No.", "CO." and "056".

I also tried:

```
all_texts = soup.find_all(":")
```

or:

```
all_texts = soup.find_all("/b")
```

etc and they don’t work.

### Results

The help below works out 2 ways. putting on there for reference:

this way get the contents of bold letters however in some sentences, the last letter is missing:

```
for bb in aa:
    cc = bb.get_text()
    dd = cc[cc.find("<b>")+1 : cc.find("</b>")]
    print dd
```

this way the ee and ff provides the 'title' and contents, which are texts before and after ":".

```
for bb in aa:
    cc = bb.get_text()
    dd = cc.split(' :')
    ee = dd[0] #title
    ff = dd[len(dd)-1] # content
```

Comment: It would be useful to know how your attempts have failed, as in the results that were returned. :)

Comment: thanks Talvalin. i've supplied them in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the findAll to get the correct section of the full HTML document, then use:

```
text = soup.get_text()
print text
```

And then break it up into arrays with '.split()'

```
for line in soup.get_text().split('\n'):
    if line != ''
        print line.split()
```

Comment: thanks philshem. and how can i get the text before and after the ":" when they are split?

Comment: In your case, print line.split()[0] gives you the things before the ":". There are more robust ways to do it, but let me know if this works for your application.

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to force yourself to use beautifulsoup functions to separate them
because for each data inside  have different token key to split
ie:

```
<TD width="40%">Company No. <I>(CO.)</I> : <B>056</B></TD>
```

1. Company No. its separated by "."
2. (CO.) its separated by ":"
3. 056 inside `<B></B>`

i suggest you use substring method to grab data from each td:

```
#grab all td
all_texts = soup.findAll("td") 
for txt in all_texts
        #convert td into string
        td = str(td)
        txt1 = td[td.find(">")+1 : td.find("<i>")] #get first data from <td>...</i>
        txt2 = td[td.find("<i>")+3 : td.find("</i>")] #get 2nd data from <i>...</i>
        txt3 = td[td.find("<b>")+3 : td.find("</b>")] #get 3rd data from <b>...</b>
        print txt1
        print txt2
        print txt3
```

Comment: thanks zlogic, the way you demonstrate provides a good thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This is just simple string manipulation, not really a BS4 issue overall. Something like follows can be done. Note that the following is maybe not the best approach, but I did it this way for verbosity.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

ofile = open("test.html")
soup = bsoup(ofile)
soup.prettify()

tds = soup.find_all("td")
templist = [td.get_text() for td in tds]

newlist = []
for temp in templist:
    whole = temp.split(":") # Separate by ":" first.
    half = whole[0].split("(") # Split the first half using open parens.
    first = half[0].strip() # First of three elements.
    second = half[1].replace(")","").strip() # Second of three elements.
    third = whole[1].strip() # Use the second element for the first split to get third of three elements.
    newlist.append([first, second, third])

for lst in newlist:
    print lst # Just print it out.
```

Result:

```
[u'Company No.', u'CO.', u'056']
[u'Country Code.', u'CC.', u'3532']
[u'Register', u'Reg.', u'FD522']
[u'Credit', u'CD.', u'YES']
[u'Type', u'TP.', u'PRIVATE']
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: thanks Nanashi for the reply. when i run it, the error message is "IndexError: list index out of range", problem is in the "half[1]". when they are changed to "half[0]", it works. anyway i need to digest them. thanks again.